# Why stackexchange sites are not mobile friendly?

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web

I use stackoverflow often. As a web developer, I notice nowadays many sites use bootstrap to be responsive web site. When you reduce the size of browser, you will see a little bit different layout and it fits to browser. Especially it's useful if you are in tablet or smartphone. I saw https://meta.stackexchange.com/ changes it's header content when you reduce browser size, but not full content. Footer exceeds from browser screen. Is there any reason why stackexchange.com sites are not responsive/mobile friendly?

PS: I'm not complaining. All stackexchange sites are cool. Just want to know reason. Maybe they are planning to do it.

**EDIT**

I don't use mobile version of stackexchange sites. So I didn't know that  there were different mobile version (and app) of the site for mobile devices. My question is only for desktop version. It's not fully responsive. I mean There shouldn't be scrollbar horizontally (Bottom of the screen). Of there could be scrollbar within question/answer body.

Comment: The sites are mobile friendly (based on useragent) but they are not responsive.

Comment: @Aziz Why target a question that was also closed as a duplicate?  Just makes the chain longer.

Comment: You're not talking about the mobile layout, right?

Comment: @Troyen: the next step in that chain doesn't directly address mobile use.

Comment: We also have a couple of mobile apps.

Comment: @rene. You're right. I'm not talking about mobile version. I don't use mobile version. I'm talking about responsive web site. Should I change the title?

Comment: @bob That is up to you. You could try the mobile view and see how that works for you. If it doesn't and you stay with your feature request I'll close it as the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the mobile version of SE sites:

Just...

> [image]

Also, in the bottom of mobile sites you'll find a link to the SE app:

> [image]

Comment: This is hardly mobile friendly though.